# DrawingGroup - crossthreading

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety, drawing, multithreading

I have a class that have two fields and some methods for drawing:

```
public class DrawingTool
{
    private readonly DrawingGroup _drawingGroup;
    private DrawingImage _imageSource;

    public DrawingTool()
    {
        _drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        _imageSource = new DrawingImage(_drawingGroup);
    }

    public DrawingImage GetImageSource()
    {
        return _imageSource;
    }

    public void DrawSomething()
    {
        using (DrawingContext dc = _drawingGroup.Open()) // HERE'S AN ERROR - _drawing group is being used by another thread (InvalidOperationException)
        {
           // draw something here
        }
    }
}
```

This is a `WPF` project, so I also have an `Image`:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="320" Height="240"></Image>
```

I set the source:

```
_drawingTool = new DrawingTool();
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyImage.Source = _drawingTool.GetImageSource());

_device.FrameReady += (sender, args) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    _drawingTool.DrawSomething();
});
```

I'm getting an error from the comment... I tried to invoke `DrawSomething()` method and use `CheckAccess()` for `_drawingGroup` inside `DrawSomething()` - didn't help. How to make it possible to work?
Thanks for help in advance!

**[edit 1.]**
Maybe I should use something different than `DrawingGroup`?

**[edit 2.]**
No one has an idea? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution... It was really obvious... I had to initialize whole drawing tool in the main thread (in the main window constructor), then set `MyImage.Source` (also in the same place). Now everything's gonna work! :)